# How can we import an @ngModule and other definitions with a tsconfig "alias path"

Tags: angular, typescript

repo: https://github.com/andreElrico/mono-repo-test

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/andreElrico/mono-repo-test (noop; only to navigate smoothly)

Let's assume the following structure:

```
root/
├── projects/
│   ├── app1
│   ├── app2
│   ├── app3
│   ├── app4
│   ├── lib1
```

- app1 - **DOES NOT WORK** << why cant I use the alias-path defined in root tsconfig? (`"@lib1": ["projects/lib1/src/public-api"]`). Its a combination of `app2` and `app4`.
- The error message for app1: `
  ERROR in projects/app1/src/app/app.component.ts:7:3 - error NG8001: 'lib-lib1' is not a known element:

  1. If 'lib-lib1' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
  2. If 'lib-lib1' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (lib-lib1 component)
     `
- app2 - **works** - is the angular guided way. It uses a `tsconfig -> path` onto the dist/lib1 (build library output)
- app3 - **works** - uses relativ paths to the EXACT file location as you all have suggested
- app4 - **works** - uses relativ paths to the `public_api.ts`.

Why cant `app1` not be compiled successfully?  Thats the case I want to work with? Path wise it should all be correct :-/ ? The reason behind why I want to make `app1` work is that I want to pull request on a library and a "test-app" already has all imports "library style" => (eg. @lib1). So its would be awesome to map the "normally" nodemodule path of "@lib1" to the exact sources of the library that are just siblings of this app. With that I can very fast debug and develop a new feature. Of course I would remove @lib1 from package.json fo the "test-app".

Comment: just import module... what are you problem?

Comment: in aap1: import {Lib1Module} from '../../sharedLibs/lib1';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the module into the providers:

https://github.com/andreElrico/mono-repo-test/blob/6939e4a36cd64a2f9df8e8abc8e3addf162a75cf/projects/app1/src/app/app.module.ts?fbclid=IwAR14_D6YilhHEsNep7azHpHPrGcMDlVAruDQa7dYDBIsBlkdGFaFyW-u-LE#L15

If you add the module to the imports array it should work as expected.

Comment: works +1 thank you ... what a stupid simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If your module is in the `apps/app1` directory and the shared component you want to import is in `sharedLibs/lib1`; just do:

```
import { component } from "../../sharedLibs/lib1"
```

You can build a system that has a lot of up and down directory traversals this approach.  My preferred approach would be a separate library in a private npm repo for anything beyond a demo project.

---

**Edit**:

To access the library through an alias without traversing the path structure; you should be able to edit the `tsconfig.json` file.

Look for compilerOptions.paths:

```
"paths": {
  "lib1/*": ["../../sharedLibs/lib1/*"],
  "lib2/*": ["../../sharedLibs/lib2/*"],
  "lib3/*": ["../../sharedLibs/lib3/*"]
}
```

These paths should be looked at for library projects before the `node_modules` is.

Comment: I will have to update my question and I will probably have to add a github repo. I want to import like I would from a library. So always `import X from 'lib1'`. I tried quite a few things. But it did not work out. I need to superwise my question.

Comment: Updated my question.